# pdf object creating memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

I have following code

```
NSString *filePath=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pdfname ofType:@"pdf" inDirectory:@"appMasterPdf"]]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
[filePath release];

CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url);
CGFloat scaleRatio; 
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(width, height));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, pageNumber);
pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFBleedBox);
width=pageRect.size.width;
height=pageRect.size.height;
if(pageRect.size.width/pageRect.size.height < 1.0) {
    scaleRatio = height/pageRect.size.height;
}
else {
    scaleRatio = width/pageRect.size.width;
}

CGFloat xOffset = 0.0;
CGFloat yOffset = height;
if(pageRect.size.width*scaleRatio<width) {
    xOffset = (width/2)-(pageRect.size.width*scaleRatio/2);
}
else {
    yOffset = height-((height/2)-(pageRect.size.height*scaleRatio/2));
}

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, xOffset, yOffset);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page,
                                                              kCGPDFBleedBox, CGRectMake(0, 0, pageRect.size.width, pageRect.size.height),
                                                              0, true);
pdfTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(pdfTransform, scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
UIImage *tempImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGContextRelease(context);
CGPDFPageRelease(page);
return tempImage;
```

This function is acalling in for loop

CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url);
These lines give me a memory leaks.
Please help me . Thanx in advanced

Answer (score 2):

From the manual of CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL, "You are responsible for releasing the object using CGPDFDocumentRelease."

So you need to call

```
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf)
```

when you are done. The general convention of CG methods is that if the name contains Create then there will be a corresponding Release method which you must call.

Comment: i added after this

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 2 lines

Comment: sorry to say that im not getting any clue :-(

Comment: pdfTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(pdfTransform, scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
UIImage *tempImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf)
I put like this

Comment: Simply release the pdf.dun't release the page

Answer (score 2):

You should not call `CGPDFPageRelease(page)` method since the page is obtained using a get method. instead, replace that call with [taskinoor's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3184681/156771) `CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf)` and you should be good to go.